# Cannot convert string from DateTimePicker control to int

Tags: c#, string, int, datetimepicker, date-parsing

I try to convert string from `DateTimePicker` control to int but when I run it happen error

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I am using epoch to convert. The format of `DateTimePicker` is `D/M/YYYY`. This is my code

```
    public static double convertToEpoce(string date)
    {
        DateTime _datetime= DateTime.ParseExact(date, "D/M/YYYY HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("vi-VN")); ;

        var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        return Convert.ToDouble((_datetime - epoch).TotalSeconds);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The format specifier you are using is not valid. It should be `d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss` in the C# code. (DateTimePicker might use different specifiers.)

- "d"   The day of the month, from 1 through 31.
- "M"   The month, from 1 through 12.
- "yyyy"    The year as a four-digit number.

There are no "D" or "YYYY" format specifiers.

For full list see [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

For working example see this [C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/j5GUhd).

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to parse the value of `DateTimePicker.Text`.

You can use `DateTimePicker.Value`, which will return a DateTime-value.

The error you get, is because of the wrong format specifier, like already stated in @GeorgPatscheider's answer.